# How to pop up a modal after a data was successfully inserted into database ?

Tags: database, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I am currently making a registration form what I want is to have a modal what will appear whenever a user has successfully registered into the database how I am able to do this ? 
this is my view

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <meta name="description" content="">
          <meta name="author" content="">
          <title>Register</title> 
           <?php echo link_tag('css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>
           <?php echo link_tag('jumbotron-narrow.css'); ?>
            <?php echo link_tag('styles/menu.css'); ?>
             <?php echo link_tag('styles/form.css'); ?>

      </head>








  <body class='bg'>

    <div class='header'>
      <img src = "<?php echo base_url() . '/images/tf_header.png' ?>"/>
  </div>



        <?php if (validation_errors()): ?>
                          <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                              <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                          </div>

                      <?php endif; ?>
 <div class ="container center-block">
  <br>
    <div class ="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Registration</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'user/addDelegate'; ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Surname:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Surname" name="surname" value="<?php echo set_value('surname'); ?>">
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstname"value="<?php echo set_value('firstname'); ?>" >
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>




        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Course" name="course" value="<?php echo set_value('course'); ?>">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
              <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email address" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
              <a href="<?php echo base_url().'user/home_register';?>" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
           </div>
        </div>


        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="footer">
      <img src = "<?php echo base_url() . '/images/tf_footer.png' ?>"/>
  </div>

    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

the controller:

```
public function addDelegate(){
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('surname', 'surname', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'firstname', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('age', 'Age', 'required|is_numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('course', 'Course', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
                if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

                    $reg_dat = array(
                        'surname' => $this->input->post('surname'),
                        'name' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                        'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
                        'course' => ($this->input->post('course')),
                        'email' => ($this->input->post('email')),

                    );

                   $this->load->view('user/home_view');
                $this->user_model->add_user($reg_dat);


         $this->load->view('user/individual_register');
                } else {
                    $this->load->view('user/individual_register');
                }

            }
```

Comment: This looks like job for AJAX, as you need to show the result of registration process, in the modal, without reloading the page. Are you looking for AJAX solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

**model**

```
class User_Model extends CI_Model
{

   public function __construct()
   {

        $this->load->database();
   }


    public function add_user($data)
    {
       if($this->db->insert('tablename', $data))
       {
            return TRUE;
       }else
       {
          return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

**controller**

```
public function addDelegate(){
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('surname', 'surname', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'firstname', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('age', 'Age', 'required|is_numeric');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('course', 'Course', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
  if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
      $this->load->view('');
  }else
  {
     $reg_dat = array(
         'surname' => $this->input->post('surname'),
         'name' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
         'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
         'course' => ($this->input->post('course')),
         'email' => ($this->input->post('email')),
     ); 
     //call method from model
     if($this->user_model->add_user($reg_dat) === TRUE)
     {
        $data['message'] = 'Insert success';
        //load your view page
        $this->load->view('user/home_view',$data);
     }else
     {
         $data['message'] = 'insert failled';
         // load your view page
         $this->load->view('user/home_view',$data);
     }

  } else {
     // load your register page
     $this->load->view('user/individual_register');
 }

}
```

**view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <title>Register</title> 
        <?php echo link_tag('css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>
        <?php echo link_tag('jumbotron-narrow.css'); ?>
        <?php echo link_tag('styles/menu.css'); ?>
        <?php echo link_tag('styles/form.css'); ?>
     <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </head>
<body class='bg'>
<div class='header'>
  <img src = "<?php echo base_url() . '/images/tf_header.png' ?>"/>
</div>
<?php if (validation_errors()): ?>
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
 </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class ="container center-block">
<br>
  <div class ="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Registration</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      <?php echo form_open(base_url('user/addDelegate'),['name' => 'addform', 'id' => 'addform', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form']) ?>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Surname:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Surname" name="surname" value="<?php echo set_value('surname'); ?>">
           </div>
           </div>
         </div>

       <div class="form-group">
         <div class="row">
             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
             <div class="col-sm-5">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstname"value="<?php echo set_value('firstname'); ?>" >
             </div>
         </div>
         </div>

       <div class="form-group">
         <div class="row">
             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course:</label>
             <div class="col-sm-5">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Course" name="course" value="<?php echo set_value('course'); ?>">
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
         <div class="row">
             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
             <div class="col-sm-5">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email address" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>">
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
             <a href="<?php echo base_url().'user/home_register';?>" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
          </div>
       </div>
     </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <img src = "<?php echo base_url('images/tf_footer.png')?>"/>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```